# Using linq with dynamic model in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

Using a dynamic model on an mvc page and attempting to use linq to "skip" and "take" in a for each loop.

However, every time I do it I get this error:
[image]

my code is this:

```
@model dynamic
@foreach (var article in Model.Articles.Take(2))
    {
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href='@Url.Action("Details", "Content", new { Id = article.Id }, null)'>
                <img class="img img-responsive" src="@(article.ImageUrl)" />
            </a>
            @article.Title
        </div>
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Take is an extension method, you need to include the namespace `using System.Linq`

In mvc razor, it would be `@using System.Linq`

Comment: @using System.Linq doesn't seem to be working, getting the exact same error as before?

Comment: Linq needs an IEnumerable..maybe try casting ? `var myarticles=((IEnumerable) Model.Articles).Cast<dynamic>()` and then use `@foreach (var article in myarticles.Take(2))`

Comment: Nailed it :-) Thanks